# Session_start not being called on logout -> login with session state using azure redis cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authorization, session-state, azure-redis-cache

As MS announced to replace shared cache to new azure redis cache i have migrated my app to use redis cache instead of azure shared cache according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690524.aspx)

Now i am facing one issue where on logout -> login it would not call session_start method where my app would set values along with user object like activities (user can perform) and some other.

While i was using inproc session state or previously azure shared cache then on logout->login it would call **logoutcallback()  >> session_start() >> AuthorizeCore()** but with redis cache it would call
**logoutcallback() >> AuthorizeCore()** , i could not figure out what is issue here?

Logout & login code is as below

```
public void Logout()
        {
            //redirect url
            var RedirectUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { controller = "Account", action = "LogoutCallback" }));

            //logout
            WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
            string signoutUrl = (WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(authModule.Issuer, RedirectUrl, null));


            Response.Redirect(signoutUrl, true);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public void LogoutCallback()
        {
            Session.Abandon();            
            Response.Redirect(Url.Content("~/"), true);
        }
```

and my web.config setting as below for redis configuration for session state

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" >
      <providers>              
        <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="[my host]" accessKey="[my key]" ssl="true"  operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1200000" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1200000"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We could not repro this issue. Can you give us a reproducible web app that we can use to investigate it further?